# How to troubleshoot video problems in the publication - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flv, netstream, streaming-flv-video

today my problem is this:

I have a transparent FLV video, and he's on my stage. In pubblicação to Flash Player it works perfectly, but for desktop, Android and IOS it does not appear ...

Already tried everything on video, NetStream and etc ... If you can help me I thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that flv is a supported format on android or IOS. You may want to try to re-render your video as well if it isn't working on desktop, perhaps it's corrupted?